azure-functions-core-tools@4 error: Cannot find module Users\tmfamin\Source\Repos\nodeV4Prog\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\lib\main.js
I installed azure-functions-core-tools@4.0.6280 in my windows machine manually as npm install was failing due to certificate issue. However when I try to run my project, I am getting the below error.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1148
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\A\Source\Repos\nodeV4Prog\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\lib\main.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1145:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:986:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:174:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

As npm install is failing, there is no azure-functions-core-tools folder under node-modules. I checked the folder where azure-functions-core-tools is installed, but the file lib\main.js is not there. I am not quite sure how npm start work if a module is installed globally in the computer, but not through npm install in the project.

DevFahim, In addition to package which you already used you can try to install https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2174087 from Link and make sure the terminal should be closed after installing the package.

Are you trying to install azure-function-core-tools in your container? or are you trying to install it in your windows or linux machine?

It's windows machine

I was following exactly the link that you mentioned in your first comment


As npm install is failing, there is no azure-functions-core-tools folder under node-modules.


It looks like the manual installation of azure-functions-core-tools didn’t set it up properly for your project. When you install a package globally, it typically doesn’t add the files to your local project directory

Always install necessary dependencies locally in your project directory using npm install.
Run npm list -g azure-functions-core-tools to confirm it’s installed globally.
C:\Users\A> npm list -g azure-functions-core-tools
C:\Users\A\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- azure-functions-core-tools@4.0.6280


Run the application:
C:\Users\A> func start
Starting Azure Functions...
[2024-09-20T10:00:00.000Z] Host started listening on http://localhost:7071
[2024-09-20T10:00:00.000Z] Job host started


Re-install locally:
C:\Users\A\Source\Repos\nodeV4Prog> npm install azure-functions-core-tools --save
npm WARN deprecated azure-functions-core-tools@4.0.6280: Please use the `func` command from the globally installed version instead.

+ azure-functions-core-tools@4.0.6280
added 1 package from 1 contributor and audited 1 package in 2.5s
found 0 vulnerabilities



Use a different network or adjusting the npm settings to bypass the certificate verification temporarily and then run again.

C:\Users\A\Source\Repos\nodeV4Prog> npm start
> my-azure-functions@1.0.0 start
> func start

Starting Azure Functions...
[2024-09-20T10:05:00.000Z] Host started listening on http://localhost:7071
[2024-09-20T10:05:00.000Z] Job host started



PS C:\Users..\Repos\nodeV4Prog> npm list -g azure-functions-core-tools
C:\Users\A\AppData\Roaming\npm
└── azure-functions-core-tools@4.0.5700
Step 2: func start (runs fine)
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.6280 Commit hash: N/A +421f0144b42047aa289ce691dc6db4fc8b6143e6 (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.834.3.22875
Step 3: local installation fails. It throws  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users..\nodeV4Prog\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\node_modules@types\node\ts4.8\stream']
and then try to install from internet again.

Use the terminal as run as administrator and run the command npm install azure-functions-core-tools --save-dev by running npm cache clean --force command will clear cache
